# Non ActiveX based Webview control in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building a winform application in .NET 2.0 (cannot use WPF). with a Webview control.
Because the application is multithreaded and the webview control is based on an ActiveX component I cannot refresh the url (WebView.navigate) by a multithreaded component such as the Timer control. Is the any other alternative for non ActiveX webview control?

Comment: That doesn't exist.  Large chunks of code with a user interface, like browsers, are never truly thread-safe.  They can't be, UI is never thread-safe.  Drop the UI requirement and you can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This is a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Hi @LynnCrumbling  gotta question for you when you get a chance, in socvr